# Microphone pre-amplifier op-Amp outputs larger voltage when Mic RL is larger

Tags: microphone, preamp

I am following TI's pdf [Non-inverting microphone pre-amplifier circuit](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa290/sboa290.pdf?ts=1690741428577&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FCIRCUIT060016) with [AOM-4544P-2-R](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/334/AOM-4544P-2-R-63716.pdf) microphone. I probe the circuit on the Vout after the op-amp, (not on the mic directly). I am playing around with the resistor and capacitor values to see practical changes. I noticed something about RL (or R6 in TI's notes).

When I use mic's load resistor RL=5k62, I get Vout+ = up to ~0.45V and Vout- = down to ~0.6V:

[image: mic pre amplifier]

But when I use a lower value resistor of RL=2k2, I get a more "uniform" output where both Vmin and Vmax are +-0.6 V respectively:

[image: mic pre amplifier]

A disclaimer, I tap my finger on the mic to generate noise, so its not 100% persistent, but I understand that there is this voltage difference and voltage uniformity when swapping RL.

So my schematic:
[image: mic pre amp]

My probing:
[image: mic probing]

Questions:

1. The expected behavior would be, since I use a lower resistor as the mic's load, I would get a larger Vout, because more current flows through the mic (just an assumption of mine), but I guess the opposite happens? TI's pdf does not mention that RL is part of any equation, it just mentions these:
   [image: pre amp mic]
   and that (but I cant tell if that is the reason behind the behavior):
   [image: mic resistor]
2. How can I read voltage below 0 V on the oscilloscope? I power the op-amp with 5/0 V. How can I see -0.6 V on its output?

Comment: Gently probe the DC voltage at **RL** (where it meets the microphone). Can you include this DC voltage in your question? If your microphone is similar to the one described in TI's app-note, this voltage should be around +2V.

Comment: A 2-wire electret capsule essentially works as a current source.  So higher load resistance makes for higher output.  As long as you are operating the capsule within the range of values it enjoys, of course.

Comment: It pleases my eyes to see an old LeCroy! But it looks like I should send you my automatic screenshot-over-gpib script...

Comment: @pipe Dont know why ppl get obsessed with old LeCroys :p . My email is on my profile, go ahead, I didnt know you could run scripts on that oscilloscope. christianidis@tutanota.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your second question first:

While the op-amp will indeed produce an output potential between 0V and +5V, with a mean DC value somewhere in that range, that DC component is removed by C16 and R9. They form a high pass filter that removes DC, and whose output will have a mean potential of 0V (no DC component present). A simple simulation will illustrate this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGP0Fp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I use V2 to produce a 1V amplitude sinusoidal potential, and V1 simply adds a DC offset of 2.5V. Here's a plot of \$V_{IN}\$ (blue) and \$V_{OUT}\$ (orange) over time:

[image]

As you can see for \$V_{OUT}\$, the DC offset has gone, and the signal is now centered about zero, which means it becomes negative to retain the sinusoidal form.

You said:

> The expected behavior would be, since I use a lower resistor as the mic's load, I would get a larger Vout, because more current flows through the mic (just an assumption of mine), but I guess the opposite happens?

The opposite happens, *larger* \$R_L\$ causes larger \$V_{OUT}\$. Here's why. You must first understand the microphone's internal construction, shown in the blue box here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fACpJj.png)</sup>

Voltage source V1 represents the microphone's capacitive diaphragm, which produces microvolts of fluctuations in response to incident sound waves.

The JFET here behaves like a voltage-controlled current sink, where the ratio of *change* in gate potential \$\Delta V_G\$ to the resulting *change* in drain current \$\Delta I_D\$ is called transconductance \$g_m\$:

$$ g_m = \frac{\Delta I_D}{\Delta V_G} $$

or

$$ \Delta I_D = g_m \times \Delta V_G \tag1 $$

In that second form, you can see than \$g_m\$ is a kind of gain, but instead of a varying output voltage, in response to a varying input voltage, the output is considered to be the current flowing through the JFET's channel.

Any change in that current will, by Ohm's law produce a change in the voltage \$V_L\$ across RL:

$$ \Delta V_L = \Delta I_D \times R_L $$

$$ \Delta I_D = \frac{\Delta V_L}{R_L} \tag2 $$

Substituting eq. 2 into eq. 1:

$$ \frac{\Delta V_L}{R_L} = g_m \times \Delta V_G $$

We can rearrange this to obtain *voltage* gain \$\frac{}{}\$:

$$ \frac{\Delta V_L}{\Delta V_G} = g_m R_L $$

In other words, whatever change in voltage occurs at gate G appears with \$g_mR_L\$ greater amplitude across \$R_L\$. Since the top of \$R_L\$ is fixed at +5V, it must be the bottom end D that is changing potential, and that's why we consider D to be the microphone's output.

Voltage gain, then, is proportional to resistance \$R_L\$. Output signal amplitude increases if \$R_L\$ increases, which can be seen in the plot below. Blue is the output OUT1 from the left circuit with \$R_L=10k\Omega\$, and orange is OUT2, on the right, where \$R_L=5k\Omega\$:

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you wrote this. +1. There are so many questions of late on electrets and it is nice to have a direct and simple reference here, of sorts, to refer to in explaining why using a higher voltage source and a larger resistor for the electret is worth some trouble doing. Getting as much as possible from the transducer/jfet system before it enters into the rest of the circuit is well-paid effort. Bookmarked for later comments I may write from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

Your supply voltage is too low for you to use a 5.6k bias resistor since the Jfet in an electret mic has a constant current (0.5mA max) if the voltage across it allows the correct current. 0.5mA in 5.6k is a voltage of 2.8V leaving only 2.2V across the mic. The 2.2k in the mic datasheet leaves 3.9V across the mic.

Your schematic is a colorful negative that is difficult to see. Most schematics have clear black wires and parts on a white background. The gain of the opamp is only 12 instead of 100 to 200.

The capacitance of your C13 is so small that it cuts frequencies lower than 17.8kHz and your tapping produces a MUCH lower single-sided pulse frequency that is probably overloading the mic.

Answer (score 1):

1. That's an electret microphone capsule; it has internal circuitry which consumes current via the RL you provide.

If you provide a correct RL value (based on how much current the mic draws), the mic output has a correct DC bias voltage with the correct bias current and the audio signal voltage can go up and down symmetrically around the bias voltage.

If you provie an incorrect RL value, lik too high resistance, the DC bias voltage is quite low so it may work poorly, be nonlinear, or other problems. As the mic would like to draw the DC bias current, it just can't decrease signal current enough for the voltage to rise high enough.

Always use the correct resistor for providing bias supply voltage/current to the mic. It will be in the mic data sheet. The mic used in TI's appnote requires 0.5mA when the voltage is 2V, which is why it must be 6 kohms to drop 5V to 2V at 0.5mA. Your mic is different.

2. You have an AC coupled output, so when you e.g. have a sine wave output from op-amp that is between 0 and 5V, the sine wave has 2.5V DC offset, so it revolves around 2.5V, and the AC coupling cap removes the DC offset so you end up with sine wave without DC offset so it revolves around 0V.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that the output should be higher with a lower RL is incorrect. Inside the microphone is an FET in a common source configuration. This is used to transform the high impedance of the mic element to a lower impedance and amplify it’s signal. The voltage gain of a common source amplifier will be roughly the ratio of the impedance in the drain circuit to the impedance in the source circuit. The impedance in the drain is RL so making it higher increases the voltage gain. The FET will have a limit to it’s gain and will need to be biased within a certain region so there’s a limit to how much the gain will increase with increasing RL, but within those limits the result you are seeing is what is expected.

With regards to your scope question, an oscilloscope will normally show both positive and negative voltages, starting with the trace on the 0 line, positive voltage with respect to the probe ground lead will make the trace go up, negative voltages will make it go down.